# How to enable / disable a JSF Command Button

Tags: jsf, primefaces

The scenario looks like this:

There are two buttons in the screen, say button1 and button2. On page load, button2 is disabled. When the user clicks button1, button2 will be enabled. I achieved this functionality using javascript window.onload event, and onclick event on button1. My problem is, when the user clicks button1 it triggers a page reload. With that being said, after the reload of the page, button2 is disabled because of the onload event.

Is there another way to achieved this functionality?

By the way I'm using primefaces.

Comment: Sounds like you could use an answer from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000669/re-enabled-pcommandbutton-not-firing-ajax

Answer (score 16, accepted):

primeface page goes like this,

```
 <p:commandButton update="panel1"  actionListener="#{bean.button1}" value="button1" disabled="#{bean.disable}"> 
     <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{false}" target="#{bean.disable}"/>   
 </p:commandButton> 


 <p:commandButton update="panel2"  actionListener="#{bean.button2}" value="button1" disabled="#{!(bean.disable)}"> 
     <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{true}" target="#{bean.disable}"/>    
 </p:commandButton>
```

Manage Bean:

```
 public class Bean {

    private boolean disable;

    // default constructor 
    public Bean(){
       this.disable= false;
    }

    public boolean isDisable() {
       return disable;
    }
    public void setDisable(boolean disable) {
       this.disable = disable;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling `actionListener`?

Comment: @Kushan: Can you please explain, why are you using `actionListener`?

Comment: disabled="#{bean.disable}" is enough. You may use only this BUT also concentrate in (boolean) isDisable logic!

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot easier way in my opinion.

Just create a `boolean` property (with getter + setter) in a `managed bean` with `javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped` and `javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean` annotated.

You can handle the disabled state via this property (button2State).

```
<h:form>
    <p:commandButton id="button1" update="button2"
        action="#{bean.setButton2State(false)}"
        value="Enable second button" />
    <p:commandButton id="button2" disabled="#{bean.button2State}"
        value="button disabled one page load" />
</h:form>
```

The first button calls the `setter` of the property and set `button2State` to `false` to enable the button. Also this example uses ajax to update the button only.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JSF 2.0, you can accomplish this using the `f:ajax` tag.

You can disable a button with a condition in a bean

```
disabled="#{bean.isDisabled}"
```

when you rerender the button when you click on button 1, the button can be enabled.