# How can I create toggle buttons in JSF?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, toggle, commandbutton

How can I create toggle buttons in JSF?

Basically, I need two buttons "in" and "out". They essentially call the same managed bean, but as a result of every click the one should be disabled and the other should be enabled and vice versa. How can this be done? Should I use ajax functionality?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just have a `boolean` property which you inverse in action method and use exactly that property in the `disabled` attribute of the both buttons, inversed.

Kickoff example:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Bean {

    private boolean enabled;

    public void toggle() {
        enabled = !enabled;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

}
```

With

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton value="Enable" action="#{bean.toggle}" disabled="#{bean.enabled}" />
    <h:commandButton value="Disable" action="#{bean.toggle}" disabled="#{not bean.enabled}" />
</h:form>
```

Ajax is technically not necessary. Feel free to add `<f:ajax>` to both buttons to improve the user experience though.

A `@ViewScoped` bean is in turn very necessary. A `@RequestScoped` one would be trashed on end of request and recreated in next request, hereby causing the `boolean` to be reinitialized to default and thus seemingly fail to work after second click, because JSF will as part of safeguard against tampered/hacked requests also check the `disabled` (and `rendered`) attribute before actually invoking the action.

#### See also:

- [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope/)
- [commandButton/commandLink/ajax action/listener method not invoked or input value not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandlink-commandbutton-ajax-backing-bean-action-listener-method-not-invoked/) (point 5)

Comment: Hi BalusC, thanks for the answer. I used it in my code where the action toggle routine is also called by a selectOneMenu (i.e the button and the menu updated values decide my operation). In this case, the toggling fails. Any idea how this can be set?

Comment: Hard to answer without seeing concrete code. Press `Ask Question` to ask a new question and put therein the code in SSCCE flavor.