# How to toggle disable in primefaces components selectOneMenu and calendar?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

How to toggle disable in primefaces components selectOneMenu and calendar ? 
Question is when user inputs value in **calendar** then *selectOneMenu* should be disabled. But when he removes value from **calendar** *selectOneMenu* should be enabled again.

I have tried with [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14692326/toggle-buttons-in-jsf-2-1) but since those components dont have action attribute I couldnt figure it out. 
I dont have validation button I wolud like to use some event.

Comment: "When user inputs value" -> Do you have a validation button then or do you want to use a JS event like `blur` to detect when it should disable or enable your `selectOneMenu`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ajax event to find out if the value has been changed.

```
<p:calendar ... >
  <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{bean.dateChange}" update="selectOneMenuId"/>
</p:calendar>
```

Then use something like this in your bean:

```
private boolean disableSelectOneMenu = true;
public void dateChange(DateSelectEvent event) {
    Date date = event.getDate();
    if (date == null) { 
        disableSelectOneMenu = true;
    } else {
        disableSelectOneMenu = false;
    }
}
```

and use the disableSelectOneMenu property in you disable tag of you selectOneMenu.

Comment: Thanks for ansewer, sorry for my ignorance, what should DateSelectEvent represent ?  SelectEvent ?

Comment: @helloWorld, in fact, `DateSelectEvent` is not present anymore in the API. You need to use the `SelectEvent` and grab de object as a `Date`. However, you haven't specified the PF version you're working with.

Comment: @GregD, I figurout your solution, but now It keeps refreshing whole page.

Comment: @helloWorld even if you specify the ajax and the correct element to update?

Answer (score 0):

Both `<p:calendar/>` and `<p:selectOneMenu>` has `disabled` properties. Both component has ajax events, `<p:calendar/>` has `dateSelect` and `<p:selectOneMenu/>` has `change`. 
So, you need to make a bean method which will return `true` or `false` according to which selection has been made and bind it to `disabled` properties and update these components when selection has been made.

For example JSF part:

```
<p:calendar id="calendar" value="#{bean.calendar}" disabled="#{bean.calendarDisabled}">
        <p:ajax event="change" update="selector calendar" process="@this"/>
</p:calendar>


<p:selectOneMenu id="selector" disabled="#{bean.calendarDisabled != true}">
    <p:ajax event="change" update="selector calendar" process="@this"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

And bean part:

```
public boolean calendarDisabled(){
     if(calendar != null){
           return false;
     }else{
         //...do whatever you needs basing on your requirements
     }
}
```

Also please take a look at [Primefaces manual](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_5_1.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for answer, I am looking at manual (now) and trying to figure it out. But selectOneMenu  is always disabled. I still cannot togle it.