Clean updated form element with AJAX without a listener
I have the next code:
<p:selectOneMenu id="select1" value="#{bean.select1}">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="--SELECT--" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{bean2.data}" var="data" itemValue="#{data.value}" itemLabel="#{data.label}/>
        <p:ajax process="@this" update="select2, select3" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
<p:selectOneMenu id="select2" value="#{bean.select2}" disabled="#{bean.select1 == null}">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="--SELECT--" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{bean2.getData(bean.select1)}" var="data" itemValue="#{data.value}" itemLabel="#{data.label}/>
        <p:ajax process="@this" update="select3" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
<p:selectOneMenu id="select3" value="#{bean.select3}" disabled="#{bean.select2 == null}">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="--SELECT--" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{bean2.getData(bean.select2)}" var="data" itemValue="#{data.value}" itemLabel="#{data.label}/>
</p:selectOneMenu>

My problem is the next:

I choose in "select1" a value, and then it updates "select2" with the list of values.
I choose in "select2" a value, for example "VALUE1".
I submit the form.
I choose in "select1" the value "--SELECT--", and then it updates "select2" leaving it disabled with the value "--SELECT--"
If I submit the form again, I get in my backbean these values: select1 == NULL and select2 == VALUE1.

I guess the issue here is that my "select2" is disabled, so that's why when I submit the form it isn't submmiting the value NULL. Is it possible to also clean the backbean value attached to the select2 when I change the select1 without using a listener?
In this example I have only 3 selectOneMenu, but in my real case I have multiple selectOneMenus in a chain, and cleaning them with a listener seems very tedious.
Ideas?
I'm using JSF 4.1, Primefaces 14 and Omnifaces 4.4.1
Thanks.

Is this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/q/32390081

Hey BalusC, it works!, but now I have another issue. What I did is to modify the disabled attribute in all my selectOneMenus to this: disabled="#{bean.selectX == null and facesContext.currentPhaseId.ordinal eq 6}". It works great with the second selectOneMenu, but with the 3rd and next selectOneMenu in the chain it doesn't disable them. I added a third level in my post so you can see how I'm updating them just in case I'm doing something wrong. Thank you very much.
